# How do i expand vector type values in a column

Tags: r

How can I expand the values in "Coderange" column? My data has two columns: CodeRange and Desc. I want to add a third column to the data frame that will contain the individual values from the vector in the codeRange column. How do I do that in R?

This is what my table looks like now

```
CodeRange  Desc   
61000:61055 Test1 
61000:61055 Test1 
61000:61055 Test1
0356T:0358T Test2  
S9090:S9090 Test3 
0062T:0062T Test4
```

This is the end result that I am hoping for

```
CodeRange  Desc   Codes(new Column to be add)
61000:61055 Test1 61001
61000:61055 Test1 61002
61000:61055 Test1 61003
61000:61055 Test1 61004
61000:61055 Test1 61005
  .
  .
61000:61055 Test1 61055
0356T:0358T Test2 0356T
0356T:0358T Test2 0357T
0356T:0358T Test2 0358T
S9090:S9090 Test3 S9090
0062T:0062T Test4 0062T
```

Comment: Please edit your question for formatting. Right now it's not clear what is what. Please provide the data in an easy-to-paste form. Either by simulating the data or outputting the actual values using `dput`. There is plenty of good advice on how to do that [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Are all codes 5 characters in length?

Comment: Yes, they are 5 characters in length

Answer (score 0):

```
dt <- read.table(text = "CodeRange  Desc   
61000:61055 Test1 
61000:61055 Test1 
61000:61055 Test1
0356T:0358T Test2  
S9090:S9090 Test3 
0062T:0062T Test4 
", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)
```

---

```
dt <- dt[!duplicated(paste(dt$CodeRange, dt$Desc)),]

expand_code <- function(x){
  code_range <- x[1]

  code_range_raw  <- as.character(unlist(strsplit(code_range, ":")))
  letters     <- stringr::str_extract(code_range, "[^0-9]")
  letters_pos <- stringr::str_locate(code_range, "[^0-9]")

  code_range <- gsub("[^0-9]", "", code_range_raw)
  code_range <- seq(from = code_range[1], to = code_range[2], by = 1)

  if(nchar(code_range_raw[1]) != nchar(code_range[1])){
    code_range <- paste0(strrep("0", 
                nchar(code_range_raw[1]) - nchar(code_range[1]) - nchar(letters[1])), 
                code_range)
  }

  if(letters_pos[[1]] == nchar(code_range_raw[1])){
      code_range <- paste0(code_range, letters[1])
  }
  if(letters_pos[[1]] < nchar(code_range_raw[1])){
      code_range <- paste0(letters[1], code_range)
  }


  data.frame(CodeRange = x[1], Desc = x[2], Code = code_range, row.names = NULL)
}

do.call("rbind", apply(dt, 1, expand_code))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df=df[!duplicated(df),] 
values=sapply(parse(text=gsub("[A-Za-z]+","",df$CodeRange)),eval)#EXPAND
dat=`row.names<-`(df[rep(1:nrow(df),lengths(values)),],NULL)#MAKE THE NEW LARGE DF
Codes=sub(":.*","",dat$CodeRange)
regmatches(Codes,regexpr("\\d+",Codes))<-sprintf("%04.0f", unlist(values))#INCLUDE THE LETTERS TO THE LARGE DF
dat$Codes=Codes

head(dat)
    CodeRange  Desc Codes
1 61000:61055 Test1 61000
2 61000:61055 Test1 61001
3 61000:61055 Test1 61002
4 61000:61055 Test1 61003
5 61000:61055 Test1 61004
6 61000:61055 Test1 61005
  tail(dat)
     CodeRange  Desc Codes
56 61000:61055 Test1 61055
57 0356T:0358T Test2 0356T
58 0356T:0358T Test2 0357T
59 0356T:0358T Test2 0358T
60 S9090:S9090 Test3 S9090
61 0062T:0062T Test4 0062T
```

One Issue is that the `data 1:3` are repeated. So then you would like to use just like to have `df=df[!duplicated(df),]` then perform the above

DATA:

```
df=read.table(text="CodeRange  Desc   
61000:61055 Test1 
               61000:61055 Test1 
               61000:61055 Test1
               0356T:0358T Test2  
               S9090:S9090 Test3 
               0062T:0062T Test4 ",h=T,stringsAsFactors=F)
```